# Mongodb transactions scalability WriteConflict

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions

I am using:

- Mongodb (v4.2.10)
- nodejs + Mongoose

I am still in the development phase of my application and I am facing a potential problem (`WriteConflict`) using transactions in mongodb.
My application gives the possibilities for users to add posts and to like posts.
When liking a post, here what is happening on the back-end side :

- Start transaction
- Find the post with the given ID in the `Post` collection
- Add a document to the `Like` collection
- Update the like count of the post in the `Post` collection
- Update the likes given count of the user in the `User` collection
- Update the likes received count of the user in the `User` collection
- Add a notification document in the `Notification` collection
- Commit the transaction

I'd say the average execution time is 1 second, so it means that for 1 second, I am locking :

- 1 `Post` document
- 2 `User` documents

I can see that as huge scalability problem, especially if a user has many popular posts that will often be liked by others.

What would you recommend me to do?

I don't think I can stop using transactions because if something goes bad during the execution of the function, I want to revert potential changes made to the DB

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are not required for this.

- Once a like is in the likes collection, you can recalculate all counts.
- Notifications cannot be calculated (since you don't know when one was sent), but generally they are ephemeral anyway and if you have an outage requiring database restore users will most likely forgive some lost notifications.

When updating counts, use $inc instead of read-modify-write (writing out the new value).

Comment: Well I want to use an atomic transaction because I don't want to create a `Like` document if, for some reason, the count couldn't be updated on the `Post` or on the `User`, or if the `Notification` couldn't be sent to the user. I am keeping the like counts (in the `Post` collection and `User` collection) so that I want to prioritize `read` over `write`. I don't think having to recalculate the like counts periodically because the transactions were not atomic is recommended.

Comment: P.S.: I am already using the $inc operator for the count update